# How to solve the stock spans problem using a stack?

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, stack, stock

I am looking at [this stock span problem](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/stock-span-problem-1587115621/1):

> The stock span problem is a financial problem where we have a series of **n** daily price quotes for a stock and we need to calculate the span of stock’s price for all **n** days.
>
> The span **S<sub>i</sub>** of the stock’s price on a given day **i** is defined as the maximum number of consecutive days just before the given day, for which the price of the stock on the current day is less than or equal to its price on the given day.

In [this description](https://slideplayer.com/slide/16508278/96/images/4/Computing+Spans+with+a+Stack.jpg) an algorithm is explained:

> #### Computing Spans with a Stack
>
> - We keep in a stack the indices of the last element that is taller when "looking back"
> - We scan the array from left to right
>
>   - Let  be the current index
>   - We pop indices from the stack until we find index  such that [] < []
>   - We set [] <=  −
>   - We push  onto the stack
>     [image]

The output for the example is supposed to be {1,1,2,1,2,3,6,1}, but my code outputs {1,1,2,2,2,3,6,7}

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 8

typedef int element;
typedef struct StackType {
    element elem[SIZE];
    int top;
} StackType;

void init(StackType *A) {
    A->top = -1;
}

int isEmpty(StackType *A) {
    return A->top == -1;
}

int isFull(StackType *A) {
    return A->top == SIZE - 1;
}

void push(StackType *A, element i) {
    if (isFull(A)) {
        printf("FULL\n");
        return;
    }
    A->top++;
    A->elem[A->top] = i;
}

element pop(StackType *A) {
    if (isEmpty(A)) {
        printf("Empty\n");
        return 0;
    }
    element temp = A->elem[A->top];
    A->top--;
    return temp;    
}

void spans(StackType *A, int X[], int S[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        while (!isEmpty(A) && (X[A->top] <= X[i]))
            pop(A);
        if (isEmpty(A))
            S[i] = i + 1;
        else
            S[i] = i - (A->top);
        push(A, i);
    }
    while (!isEmpty(A))
        pop(A);
    return;
}

int main() {
    StackType A;
    init(&A);
    int X[SIZE] = { 60, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30, 50, 40 };
    int S[SIZE];
    spans(&A, X, S);
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        printf("[%d] ", S[i]);  
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I debugged the function `void spans`, and I saw `A->top` doesn't change in the right way. For example, when `i = 2`, `A->top` should be `2`, but in reality, `A->top` is `1`. There seems something wrong with function `pop` and `push`, but I couldn't find the problem.

Comment: We cannot help you if we do not know what this code is supposed to do functionally.  Please tell us the function or specs for this code.

Comment: Are you sure that the stack structure and its functions are working correctly? Have you tried to test and debug only those parts first before  working on the span function?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Well, we're always hounding posters about how easy it is to google things, and if you search on "stock span", the first two hits are on — surprise, surprise — geeksforgeeks and leetcode.

Comment: @4386427 I'm suggesting, perhaps the OP assumed that "stock spans" were as well known as, say, "prime numbers", and I can't really fault that assumption, especially since, even though I didn't know, it was so trivial for me to educate myself.

Comment: @SteveSummit Problem descriptions are supposed to be included in the question.  Even if the OP included a link to LeetCode etc., the description is not supposed to rely on external websites.  If "stock span" is a standard problem/description in CS and that is sufficient to describe the OPs code's functional code, then I would withdraw my concern, but I've never heard of it before and neither LeetCode nor GeeksForGeeks are an authoritative guide of such. (for start, they frequently misname even standard well-known problems like the Change-Making Problem).

Comment: @RBarryYoung I had never heard of "stock span" either, and I know (from my perspective) that it's not as well-known a problem as prime or Fibonacci or Armstrong numbers, but I can't fault the OP for not knowing that, and it took me less time to answer the question than it would have taken me to scold the OP about it.

Comment: @SteveSummit That's great.  Please feel free to answer the question then.  I personally do not have time to research things that the OP already knows and could easily have included in their question, so I will move on to other questions that already have the necessary information in them.

Comment: @SteveSummit IMO you are too kind

Comment: @RBarryYoung That's perfectly fine.  Obviously none of us knows enough to answer every question.  But you didn't just move on — you first took time to scold the OP.

Comment: One cannot be too kind.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your implementation is that `A->top` is an *index*, not the *value* stored at the top of the stack.

So I would suggest defining a function to retrieve the top *value* from the stack:

```
element peek(StackType *A) {
    if (isEmpty(A)) {
        printf("Empty\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return A->elem[A->top];
}
```

And then in the function `spans` replace all occurrences of `A->top` with `peek(A)`. I have also changed the `if...else` construct to a ternary operator:

```
void spans(StackType *A, int X[], int S[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        while (!isEmpty(A) && (X[peek(A)] <= X[i]))
            pop(A);
        S[i] = i + (isEmpty(A) ? 1 : -peek(A));
        push(A, i);
    }
    while (!isEmpty(A))
        pop(A);
    return;
}
```

Last remark: I would not define the stack in `main`, but in `spans`.

Comment: thx!!!! for your answer I solve this problem