# Find out how many values are smaller up to a value in an array

Tags: java, algorithm

#### The problem is the following:

Let P be an array of positive integers. I need to create an array S according to this definition:

S[i] contains the number of elements that are smaller or equal to P[i].

**This must be achieved in linear time - O(n).**

Example: if P=[2,7,4,5,9,12], then S=[0,1,0,1,4,5].

That's because P[0] has zero elements smaller or equal to it (up to P[0]), so S[0]=0, and P[1] only has P[0] smaller than it (up to P[1]), so S[1]=1, and so on.

#### Here's my attempt (in Java):

My attempt is making a single pass on the array and utilizes a stack to store the previous indices in P. This, sadly, is a failed attempt, because for the input P=[17,4,2,0,15] the output is incorrect.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
public static int[] build_s(int[] p) {
    IntegerStack temp = new IntegerStack(p.length);
    temp.push(0);
    int[] s = new int[p.length];
    int max = p[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        if (p[i] >= max) {
            s[i] = i+1;
            max = p[i];
        } else if (p[i-1] > p[i]) {
            if (p[i] > temp.peek())
                temp.push(i);
            s[i] = 1;
        } else {
            s[i] = (i - temp.peek());
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

I would really appreciate any help in making my algorithm work properly. I can see that the problem arises when there's a sequence such as 4,2,0,15 that breaks the algorithm, but I couldn't figure out a solution in O(n) time.

Thank you!

Comment: Include test data as well since you have almost runnable example.

Comment: I mean in the code ofc.

Comment: The example `S[i]` doesn't look *the number of elements that are smaller or equal to P[i]*. It looks *the number of elements P[j] ≤ P[i] where j < i and for no k, j<k<i P[i] < P[k]*: explain `S[3]` == 1.

Comment: I don't think I understand the purpose of `temp` here. What indices is it supposed to hold? There is a check `if (p[i] > temp.peek())`. I couldn't follow this comparison of an index to a value, that's why the question

Comment: Is it known that there is an O(n) solution ?

Comment: It's possible that the problem OP is really trying to solve is a variant of the [Stock span problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69525365/how-to-solve-the-stock-spans-problem-using-a-stack), in which case that link is a good dupe. (The difference is that the count in OP's example is off by one, so that it counts previous days. But the algorithm is essentially the same.) As written, as pointed out in [an answer by @robinjagal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70295428/1566221), the O(n) constraint is not achievable

Answer (score 2):

In linear time complexity i.e. `O(n)` it is not possible to find the count of elements that smaller or equal numbers to it present in the left side of current position.

Let's **assume** that such an algorithm exists with `O(N)` time complexity. Then by using the resultant from this "algorithm", once applying in the original given array and then once after reversing it, we can find the sorted array in `O(N)` time.

Now we know that, even in the best case scenario, sorting an array made up of random integers has a time complexity of `O(N*logN)`.

Hence, our assumption is wrong and such algorithm **doesn't exist**.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this in `O(nlog(n))` is by using a `Fenwick/BIT`. But the `BIT` construction space requires an array with `size` equal to `maximum` value in your array (*provided all your elements in the array are positive*). The construction of `BIT` array is `O(size)`. for each element in your array, you need to insert `1` as the value inside your `BIT` array, Each query for a number of elements smaller than the current element will be of `O(log(size))`. So the total time complexity will be `O(sizelog(size))`. Here `size` is the length of your `BIT` array. you can learn more about `BIT` [here](https://www.topcoder.com/thrive/articles/Binary%20Indexed%20Trees)